In Python, how to compare the value to each subsequent value in a row until a condition is met
I have a table in the general structure below:

example code:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'ID': [117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117],
    'Date': ['2023-11-14', '2024-01-25', '2024-02-01', '2024-02-04', '2024-02-11', '2024-03-04']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

What I would like to do is, compare the first row to the next row, until the difference between the dates meets some threshold, say 30 days. Then, once that row meets the threshold, I'd like to then test the next row against the subsequent row. It would look like this:
Result, using threshold of 30:

So to reiterate, its comparing the FIRST row to subsequent rows until some threshold is met. Then the count starts over at the first rep after that within the group to subsequent rows within the group.
I've tried this but so far I haven't been able to get the right rowwise comparison to even implement the thresholding bit.
thres = 30

i = 0
control = True
for record in df['Date']:
    if record > thres:
            print(i, 'in position!', i)
        control = False
    i += 1


Update
I want to do the above with groups based on ID.

example code:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "ID": [117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118],
    "Date": ["2023-11-14", "2024-01-25", "2024-02-01", "2024-02-04", "2024-02-11", "2024-03-04",
             "2024-01-02", "2024-01-28", "2024-02-04", "2024-02-18", "2024-03-11", "2024-06-05"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

desired output:


Can we consider both ID and Date as the factor? For example, the date calculation should happen for member 117 and same date calculation should happen of we have multiple members for example member 118, 119 etc.

Code
maybe need loop
# example code
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': [117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117], 'Date': ['2023-11-14', '2024-01-25', '2024-02-01', '2024-02-04', '2024-02-11', '2024-03-04']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# make variable dates (convert dtype to datetime)
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# chk 30 days (you can change your target by changing variable thresh)
thresh = 30

# date is compared as variable ref
ref = dates.iloc[0]

# variable result is list to hold the flags. First element is 1
result = [1]

# append flag(0 or 1) to result variable based on 30 days (loop)
for date in dates.iloc[1:]:
    if (date - ref).days >= thresh:
        result.append(1) # append 1 as a flag if over 30 days
        ref = date # change refrence date
    else:
        result.append(0) # append 0 as a flag unless over 30 days

# make flag column using result variable 
out = df.assign(flag=result)

out
    ID  Date        flag
0   117 2023-11-14  1
1   117 2024-01-25  1
2   117 2024-02-01  0
3   117 2024-02-04  0
4   117 2024-02-11  0
5   117 2024-03-04  1


chk with new sample
df = (pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2024-01-01', '2024-04-01'), columns=['Date'])
        .sample(10, random_state=3).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
)

If apply the above code to the new sample(df), you get the following result
out:
    Date                 Date       flag
0   2024-01-10      0   2024-01-10  1
1   2024-02-15      1   2024-02-15  1
2   2024-02-22      2   2024-02-22  0
3   2024-02-25      3   2024-02-25  0
4   2024-02-28  ->  4   2024-02-28  0
5   2024-03-09      5   2024-03-09  0
6   2024-03-11      6   2024-03-11  0
7   2024-03-25      7   2024-03-25  1
8   2024-03-26      8   2024-03-26  0
9   2024-03-31      9   2024-03-31  0


Answer of updated question
Replace the above with a custom function and apply the custom function with groupby + apply.
# example code
import pandas as pd
data = {"ID": [117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118], "Date": ["2023-11-14", "2024-01-25", "2024-02-01", "2024-02-04", "2024-02-11", "2024-03-04","2024-01-02", "2024-01-28", "2024-02-04", "2024-02-18", "2024-03-11", "2024-06-05"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# make custom function
def get_flag(d, thresh=30):
    dates = pd.to_datetime(d['Date'])
    ref = dates.iloc[0]
    result = [1]

    for date in dates.iloc[1:]:
        if (date - ref).days >= thresh:
            result.append(1)
            ref = date 
        else:
            result.append(0)
    return d.assign(flag=result)
    
# groupby + apply + custom function    
out = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(get_flag)

out:
     ID        Date  flag
0   117  2023-11-14     1
1   117  2024-01-25     1
2   117  2024-02-01     0
3   117  2024-02-04     0
4   117  2024-02-11     0
5   117  2024-03-04     1
6   118  2024-01-02     1
7   118  2024-01-28     0
8   118  2024-02-04     1
9   118  2024-02-18     0
10  118  2024-03-11     1
11  118  2024-06-05     1


thank you! @panda-kim. Is it possible to do the calculation for each ID as seen in the updated sample screenshot?

@Abhinav I answered the question as per your request, and I don't think it's good behaviour to change the question. Answers on stackoverflow are for everyone, not just the questioner, and you've rendered my answer useless.

sorry, I thought if anybody is answering the question, he will consider both ID and Date as the factors. I've reverted the change.

@Abhinav Create a new question divided into groups. I'll solve it for you.

thanks but unfortunately, it looks like I've been blocked from asking new questions.

@Abhinav If so, create an "update" part on the main post and add the new question

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Abhinav i update your question & update my answer for solving your additional question.
